# How to update different values for multiple records in Sqlite android ?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table.i want to duplicate same records multiple times with one column change values ( for time). i am able to duplicate records by using below query.

```
insert into acsl_details(userID,aadhar_no 
,date ,time ,in_out 
,deptid ,emptype ,compy_code ,empmode ,name 
,upload_flag ,main_compcode ,utc_date ,utc_time ,time_zone ,latitude ,longitude )
select * from acsl_details;
```

now i have a thousand duplicate records.now i want to change the one column that is time.i need to update different time for all thousand records. i searched but unable to understand those queries.any help..

Comment: by which criteria you want to change the time? like if (<something>), then time should be <something else>

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienkono criteria or condition i just want to update time for all records ..and time in 12 hour or 24 hour format no problem

Comment: you said that you `need to update different time for all thousand records` does that mean that you want one record to have 5:00 AM, and the other - 10 AM for example?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko seconds need to be diffent for all records like 5:01:01 and 5:01:06

Comment: and how exactly you decide which time you need to set to which record?

Comment: randomly any time to any record no conditions only time (in seconds) needs to be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following will do what you are asking, that is to update the time column for the 1000 existing rows with a randomly generated time in the format hh:mm:ss :-

```
WITH RECURSIVE newdata(id_of_row,newtime) AS (
    SELECT rowid AS id_of_row , 
         time(strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00') +
             abs(random() % (strftime('%s', '2000-01-31 23:59:59') -
                                strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00'))
                   ),
                'unixepoch') AS dt
    FROM acsl_details
)
UPDATE acsl_details 
    SET time = (
        SELECT newdata.newtime 
            FROM newdata 
            WHERE newdata.id_of_row = acsl_details.rowid
    );
```

The Core code/SQL is :-

```
SELECT rowid AS id_of_row , 
 time(strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00') +
            abs(random() % (strftime('%s', '2000-01-31 23:59:59') -
                            strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00'))
               ),
            'unixepoch') AS dt
FROM acsl_details
```

This extracts the rowid's from the table adding a randomly generated time resulting in two columns (**id_of_row** and **dt**) for each row of the acsl_details table.

This, i.e. **newdata** then drives the updates. An update being done for each row that exists in **newdata**.

#### Testing

The following was used to create 100 identical rows :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS acsl_details;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acsl_details (userID integer, aadhar_no INTEGER, date INTEGER, time INTEGER, in_out INTEGER, deptid INTEGER, compy_code INTEGER, empmode INTEGER, name TEXT, upload_flag INTEGER, main_compcode TEXT, utc_date INTEGER, utc_time, time_zone, latitude REAL, longitude REAL);

WITH RECURSIVE counter(userid,aadhar,date,time,in_out,deptid,compy_code,empmode,name,upload_flag,main_compcode,utc_date,utc_time,time_zone,latitude,longitude) AS (
    SELECT 1,11,'2018-01-01','10:20:00',0,111,56078,25,'FRED',4,'PARTIAL',5000,1324,'Z',123.56,56.234 
    UNION ALL SELECT userid,aadhar,date,time,in_out,deptid,compy_code,empmode,name,upload_flag,main_compcode,utc_date,utc_time,time_zone,latitude,longitude FROM counter LIMIT 100)  
    INSERT INTO  acsl_details SELECT * FROM counter;
    
SELECT * FROM acsl_details;
```

e.g. :-

[image]

After running the code as per the solution :-

[image]

Comment: How do i make userid auoncrement in last updated table?

Comment: **Part1** You would use `userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` when defining the column, this makes it an alias of the rowid, it will then likely increment (there is no guarantee that you get 1,2,3......... but each would be a unique 64bit signed integer). e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acsl_details (userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, aadhar_no INTEGER, date INTEGER, time INTEGER, in_out INTEGER, deptid INTEGER, compy_code INTEGER, empmode INTEGER, name TEXT, upload_flag INTEGER, main_compcode TEXT, utc_date INTEGER, utc_time, time_zone, latitude REAL, longitude REAL);`

Comment: **Part2** you then do not insert a value (null is equivalent) so then use :- `WITH RECURSIVE counter(userid,aadhar,date,time,in_out,deptid,compy_code,empmode,name,upload_flag,main_compcode,utc_date,utc_time,time_zone,latitude,longitude) AS (
    SELECT null,11,'2018-01-01','10:20:00',0,111,56078,25,'FRED',4,'PARTIAL',5000,1324,'Z',123.56,56.234 
    UNION ALL SELECT userid,aadhar,date,time,in_out,deptid,compy_code,empmode,name,upload_flag,main_compcode,utc_date,utc_time,time_zone,latitude,longitude FROM counter LIMIT 100)  
    INSERT INTO  acsl_details SELECT * FROM counter;` (null not 1)

Answer (score 1):

Just list the values you want in the `select`:

```
insert into acsl_details (userID,aadhar_no, date, time, in_out, 
                          deptid, emptype, compy_code, empmode, name 
                          upload_flag, main_compcode  utc_date, utc_time,
                          time_zone, latitude, longitude
                         )
    select userID, aadhar_no, date,
           <new time value goes here>,
           in_out, 
           deptid, emptype, compy_code, empmode, name 
           upload_flag, main_compcode  utc_date, utc_time,
           time_zone, latitude, longitude                         
    from acsl_details;
```